# SRCDS not receiving connections on the public web

Tags: hosting, garrys-mod, networking, source-engine

My Garry's Mod Source DS can connect over LAN, but not externally. Ports 27015-27016 are opened and directed towards the machine running it. I can telnet into it and canyouseeme can see it running, but the Source client can't connect for some reason. Any idea of what can be going on? I'm running it on Fedora Linux Server with the firewall disabled. What's weird is that I'm hosting a web server (UDP + TCP port 80) and Mumble server (UDP + TCP port 64738) on it as well, and both are publicly accessible.

Here's my `server.cfg` if needed:

```
"ip"                "[external IP]"
"hostname"          "memes"
"maxplayers"        "12"
"sv_password"       "[password]"
"sbox_noclip"       "1"
"sbox_maxprops"     "4000"
"sbox_maxeffects"   "4000"
"sbox_maxemitters"  "4000"
"sbox_maxthrusters" "4000"
"sbox_maxsents"     "4000"
"sv_loadingurl"     "[loading page]"
```

And the script I use to start it up:

```
./srcds_run -game garrysmod +map gm_construct +maxplayers 12 -authkey [authkey] +host_workshop_collection [some addon IDs]
```

Comment: Try adding the IP to the startup script you have. Sometimes external connections are kept out by the fact that some parameters (such as IP) can be overlooked in .cfg files.

Comment: @Adam I gave up and used DigitalOcean since there aren't any networking restrictions. I also have tried that though.